# MySQL server instance will never start. Mac OS Lion

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion

I installed MySQL using the DMG file (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), and I installed the MySQL_etc.pkg, the MySQLStartUpItem.pkg and the MySQL.prefPane items.

Every time I try to start mysql from the command line I get the message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Thanks to various posts on stackoverflow I discovered that this was because MySQL was not running. So I go to the MySQL pane in System Preferences and sure enough "The MySQL Server Instance is stopped". I click "Start MySQL Server" and I get the spinning beach ball for 2 minutes, then nothing happens. The MySQL Server Instance stays stopped.

If I restart my computer then I can go to the MySQL pane and it tells me that "The MySQL Server Instance is running". And sure enough **mysql -v** at the command line tells me my MySQL connection id, and that I have server version 5.6.10. But then if I leave mysql by typing exit the server instance stops, and I can only restart it by restarting my computer!

Any ideas? I haven't even been able to run MySQL for long enough to set passwords, let along create a database!

Answer (score 3):

After an afternoon of false leads (I don't mean to sound ungrateful, all suggestions were followed up and I'm thankful for all advice), I uninstalled all traces of MySQL and reinstalled an older version, following the advice on this blog: http://soatechlab.blogspot.com/2011/01/completely-remove-mysql-on-mac-os-x.html

It appears to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
prompt$ sudo mysqld -u root <secure password goes here!>
```

Note the sudo: MySQL wouldn't let me start up the server without root access to both the computer and MySQL itself. Also note that the program is mysqld, not mysql.

The command varies depending on how you installed MySQL. Try this first:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

If that fails:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql
 sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
(Enter your password, if necessary)
 (Press Control-Z)
 bg
```

I havent' tried this, but check this out if you are working with MAMP and php:-

http://twob.net/journal/fix-for-mamp-mysql/

Maybe even try a re-install and follow these docs:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/macosx-installation.html

In addition, plenty of brainstorming on this page:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m